# (Xamatin.Forms) Is there a possible way of retrieving data from an unknown child for both iOS and Android?

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I am attempting to retrieve data from Firebase like this:

categories:

- unknown category 1:

  - unknown partner 1a:

    - Data I want to retrieve.
  - unwanted data.
- unknown category 2:

  - unknown partner 2a:

    - Data I want to retrieve.
  - unknown partner 2b:

    - Data I want to retrieve.

The tutorials I checked all require that you know the name of the child like so:

> 1. public class MyUser { public string username; public string password;
>    public DateTime createdtime; }
> 2. MyUser myUserData = new MyUser(); myUserData.username = "user1"; myUserData.password = "pswd1"; myUserData.createdtime = now;
> 3. await this.firebase .Child("users") .Child(myUserData.username) .Child("password") .WithAuth(auth.FirebaseToken) .PutAsync("newPassword");

Comment: If you use `FirebaseDatabase.net` this nuget package in the xamarin forms. No, If you want to query the database, you must know the name of child.

Comment: Are there any update for this issue?

Comment: Not really, I have decided to tackle this at a later stage as I have other stuff to do for the worked upon project. My thinking brought me to simulate a datastream using a standard var and linq, but it is still just thinking.

Comment: Ok.Just do it. If you have other issues, you can open a new thread.